# jQuery/javascript replace tag type

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagname

Is there an easy way to loop through all td tags and change them to th? (etc).

My current approach would be to wrap them with the th and then remove the td, but then I lose other properties etc.

Comment: You want to maintain the attributes currently on the `<td>`?

Comment: Yeah. I'd want to maintain everything about them.

Comment: Any reason this can't be done on the server?  This isn't trivially done on the client, at least not to handle all possible cases, the an element's tag type is immutable once added to the DOM.

Comment: You may want to consider an alternative default DOM structure to achieve whatever effect you aim to accomplish. Your operation can be done, but as Nick said, it's no simple task, especially if your number of td tags can be a variable amount.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Completely untested, but giving this a whirl:

```
$("td").each(function(index) {
  var thisTD = this;
  var newElement = $("<th></th>");
  $.each(this.attributes, function(index) {
    $(newElement).attr(thisTD.attributes[index].name, thisTD.attributes[index].value);
  });
  $(this).after(newElement).remove();
});
```

I'm looking and looking at it, and I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work!

1) loop through each td element

2) create a new th element

3) for each of those td's, loop over each of its attributes

4) add that attribute and value to the new th element

5) once all attributes are in place, add the element to the DOM right after the td, and remove the td

**Edit:** works fine: http://jsbin.com/uqofu3/edit

Comment: Works great! And if you want to copy the element inner html you can add this $(newElement).html($(this).html()); before the last line.

Answer (score 25):

## jQuery.replaceTagName

The following is a jQuery plugin to replace the tag name of DOM elements.

### Source

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replaceTagName = function(replaceWith) {
        var tags = [],
            i    = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            var newElement = document.createElement(replaceWith),
                thisi      = this[i],
                thisia     = thisi.attributes;
            for (var a = thisia.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                var attrib = thisia[a];
                newElement.setAttribute(attrib.name, attrib.value);
            };
            newElement.innerHTML = thisi.innerHTML;
            $(thisi).after(newElement).remove();
            tags[i] = newElement;
        }
        return $(tags);
    };
})(window.jQuery);
```

#### Minified Source

```
(function(e){e.fn.replaceTagName=function(t){var n=[],r=this.length;while(r--){var i=document.createElement(t),s=this[r],o=s.attributes;for(var u=o.length-1;u>=0;u--){var a=o[u];i.setAttribute(a.name,a.value)}i.innerHTML=s.innerHTML;e(s).after(i).remove();n[r]=i}return e(n)}})(window.jQuery);
```

### Usage

Include the above minified source in your javascript after jQuery.

Then you can use the plugin like this:

```
$('div').replaceTagName('span'); // replace all divs with spans
```

Or in your case this:

```
$('td').replaceTagName('th');
```

jQuery selectors work as expected

```
$('.replace_us').replaceTagName('span'); // replace all elements with "replace_us" class with spans
$('#replace_me').replaceTagName('div'); // replace the element with the id "replace_me"
```

### More resources

[jsFiddle with Qunit tests](http://jsfiddle.net/xkt5q/2/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$("td").each(function() {
  var tmp = $('<div/>').append($(this).clone(true)).html().replace(/td/i,'th');
  $(this).after(tmp).remove();
});
```

or pure DOM

```
function replaceElm(oldTagName, newTagName, targetElm) {
  var target = targetElm || window.document;
  var allFound = target.getElementsByTagName(oldTagName);
  for (var i=0; i<allFound.length; i++) {
    var tmp = document.createElement(newTagName);
    for (var k=0; k<allFound[i].attributes.length; k++) {
      var name = allFound[i].attributes[k].name;
      var val = allFound[i].attributes[k].value;
      tmp.setAttribute(name,val);
    }
    tmp.innerHTML = allFound[i].innerHTML;
    allFound[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tmp, allFound[i]);
    allFound[i].parentNode.removeChild(allFound[i]);
  }
}

replaceElm('td','th',document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]);
```

DOM is always faster: http://jsperf.com/replace-tag-names

Comment: In your jQuery solution, the regex will be applied to the whole html content which could give unexpected result.

Answer (score 3):

This might work, but I haven't tested it extensively:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
while(tds[0]){
    var t = document.createElement("th");
    var a = tds[0].attributes;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) t.setAttribute(a[i].nodeName,a[i].nodeValue);
    t.innerHTML = tds[0].innerHTML;
    tds[0].parentNode.insertBefore(t,tds[0]);
    tds[0].parentNode.removeChild(tds[0]);
}
```

I hope it helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Slight addition to @GlenCrawford answer, to also preserve inner text with the line:

```
newElement.text($(value).text());
```

All together now:

```
$("td").each(function(index) {
  var thisTD = this;
  var newElement = $("<th></th>");
  newElement.text($(value).text());
  $.each(this.attributes, function(index) {
    $(newElement).attr(thisTD.attributes[index].name, thisTD.attributes[index].value);
  });
  $(this).after(newElement).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this question is pretty old but this could help anyway: the only jQuery plugin that actually works as expected (you can't reuse the returned object in the other one, to add attributes for example):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    replaceTagName: function(replaceWith) {
        var tags=[];
        this.each(function(i,oldTag) {
            var $oldTag=$(oldTag);
            var $newTag=$($("<div />").append($oldTag.clone(true)).html().replace(new RegExp("^<"+$oldTag.prop("tagName"),"i"),"<"+replaceWith));
            $oldTag.after($newTag).remove();
            tags.push($newTag.get(0));
        });

        return $(tags);
    }
});
```

Besides the basic `$("td").replaceTagName("th");` you can also chain calls like `$("td").replaceTagName("th").attr("title","test");`

Minified version:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({replaceTagName:function(a){var b=[];this.each(function(d,c){var e=$(c);var f=$($("<div />").append(e.clone(true)).html().replace(new RegExp("^<"+e.prop("tagName"),"i"),"<"+a));e.after(f).remove();b.push(f.get(0))});return $(b)}});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cleaner than @GlenCrawford's answer and additionally copies the children of the replaced element.

```
$('td').each(function(){
    var newElem = $('<th></th>', {html: $(this).html()});
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
        newElem.attr(this.name, this.value);
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(newElem);
});
```

Comment: It is not usefull to post another answer 4 years after the question (which is already accepted) was asked.

Comment: While this source code may provide an answer, a few words of explanation would benefit current and future readers.

Comment: Added some explanations.