# jQuery: how to change tag name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dhtml

jQuery: how to change tag name?

For example:

```
<tr>
    $1
</tr>
```

I need

```
<div>
    $1
</div>
```

Yes, I can

1. Create DOM element <div>
2. Copy tr content to div
3. Remove tr from dom

But can I make it directly?

PS:

```
    $(tr).get(0).tagName = "div";
```

results in `DOMException`.

Comment: In this special case, it would not make sense to just "rename" it because `div` won't be a valid element where `tr` is located.

Comment: See this post for a more complete solution that includes all attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815683/jquery-javascript-replace-tag-type

Comment: you can also use `display:block` to make a `tr` act and look like a `div` without actually changing the tag name but you would probably want to `display:block`ify the inner `td`s as well with something like `tr,tr>td{display:block}`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can replace any HTML markup by using jQuery's `.replaceWith()` method.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/JHmaV/

Ref.: .[replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

If you want to keep the existing markup, you could use code like this:

```
$('#target').replaceWith('<newTag>' + $('#target').html() +'</newTag>')
```

Comment: This will work, but you won't carry over the dom element's properties (styles, events) etc. I don't think there exists a good way to really achieve a full node name change.

Comment: Sorry, it is NOT a "rename", it destroy all contents (all innerHTML changes!).

Comment: it is a replace, not rename!

Comment: Well to keep events etc of the contents, one could have `.replaceWith($('<newTag>').append($('#target').contents())`

Answer (score 48):

No, it is not possible according to W3C specification: "tagName of type DOMString, readonly"

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html

Comment: I thing que puchu's question is only about "rename procedure" (!), and there are a "DOM ugly way" to do rename:  1) `createElement(new_name)` 2) copy all content to new element; 3) replace old to new by `replaceChild()`

Answer (score 18):

The above solutions wipe out the existing element and re-create it from scratch, destroying any event bindings on children in the process.

**short answer:** (loses <p/>'s attributes)

```
$("p").wrapInner("<div/>").children(0).unwrap();
```

**longer answer:** (copies <p/>'s attributes)

```
$("p").each(function (o, elt) {
  var newElt = $("<div class='p'/>");
  Array.prototype.slice.call(elt.attributes).forEach(function(a) {
    newElt.attr(a.name, a.value);
  });
  $(elt).wrapInner(newElt).children(0).unwrap();
});
```

[fiddle with nested bindings](http://jsfiddle.net/rc296owo/3/)

It would be cool to copy any bindings from the  at the same time, but [getting current bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138543/list-all-bindings-of-an-element-with-jquery) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 16):

### Where the DOM renameNode() Method?

Today (2014) no browser understand the [new DOM3 renameNode method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_renamenode.asp) (see [also W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html))
check if run at your bowser:     http://jsfiddle.net/k2jSm/1/

So, a DOM solution is ugly and I not understand **why (??) jQuery not implemented a workaround?**

### pure DOM algorithm

1. `createElement(new_name)`
2. copy all content to new element;
3. replace old to new by `replaceChild()`

is something like this,

```
function rename_element(node,name) {
    var renamed = document.createElement(name); 
    foreach (node.attributes as a) {
        renamed.setAttribute(a.nodeName, a.nodeValue);
    }
    while (node.firstChild) {
        renamed.appendChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    return node.parentNode.replaceChild(renamed, node);
}
```

... wait review and jsfiddle ...

### jQuery algorithm

The @ilpoldo algorithm is a good start point,

```
   $from.replaceWith($('<'+newname+'/>').html($from.html()));
```

As others commented, it need a attribute copy ... wait generic ...

specific for `class`, **preserving the attribute**, see http://jsfiddle.net/cDgpS/

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468280/287948

Answer (score 8):

To preserve the internal content of the tag you can use the accessor `.html()` in conjunction with `.replaceWith()`

forked example: http://jsfiddle.net/WVb2Q/1/

Comment: how about saving all attributes of any element?

Comment: just what i was searching for +1. Attributes are not included with other solutions, until now, this one is a better one

Comment: No, it doesn't preserve the attributes.

Comment: Yes... But it is in the right direction! It is a "rename procedure"...  Complement it with a attribute-copy, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6753486/287948,  or using [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [ericP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243605/ericp) answer, formatted and converted to jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.replaceWithTag = function(tagName) {
    var result = [];
    this.each(function() {
        var newElem = $('<' + tagName + '>').get(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
            newElem.setAttribute(
                this.attributes[i].name, this.attributes[i].value
            );
        }
        newElem = $(this).wrapInner(newElem).children(0).unwrap().get(0);
        result.push(newElem);
    });
    return $(result);
};
```

Usage:

```
$('div').replaceWithTag('span')
```

Answer (score 6):

Working pure DOM algorithm

```
function rename_element(node, name) {
    let renamed = document.createElement(name);

    Array.from(node.attributes).forEach(attr => {
        renamed.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);        
    })
    while (node.firstChild) {
        renamed.appendChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(renamed, node);
    return renamed;
}
```

Comment: Pretty modern code, and works. Usage example: `$('blockquote').each(function(){let ren = rename_element(this, 'div'); $(ren).doMoreJqueryStuff()})`

Answer (score 3):

You could go a little basic. Works for me.

```
var oNode = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];

var inHTML = oNode.innerHTML;
oNode.innerHTML = '';
var outHTML = oNode.outerHTML;
outHTML = outHTML.replace(/tr/g, 'div');
oNode.outerHTML = outHTML;
oNode.innerHTML = inHTML;
```

Comment: It is not jQuery and is replace string is not a secure or generic strategy, use DOM or jQuery.

Comment: `<div data-divanslation="now you are in divouble">...</div>`

Answer (score 2):

To replace the internal contents of *multiple* tags, each with their own original content, you have to use `.replaceWith()` and `.html()` differently:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcrca/VYxxG/

Comment: It is a copy of @ilpoldo solution, and can be better as commented there. A copy-solution must be deleted.

Comment: I used this as jquery mobile sometimes generates double selects

Answer (score 2):

JS to change the tag name

```
/**
 * This function replaces the DOM elements's tag name with you desire
 * Example:
 *        replaceElem('header','ram');
 *        replaceElem('div.header-one','ram');
 */
function replaceElem(targetId, replaceWith){
  $(targetId).each(function(){
    var attributes = concatHashToString(this.attributes);
    var replacingStartTag = '<' + replaceWith + attributes +'>';
    var replacingEndTag = '</' + replaceWith + '>';
    $(this).replaceWith(replacingStartTag + $(this).html() + replacingEndTag);
  });
}
replaceElem('div','span');

/**
 * This function concats the attributes of old elements
 */
function concatHashToString(hash){
  var emptyStr = '';
  $.each(hash, function(index){
    emptyStr += ' ' + hash[index].name + '="' + hash[index].value + '"';
  });
  return emptyStr;
}
```

Related fiddle is in this [link](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/dynamically-change-html-tag-of-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

Since `replaceWith()` didn't work for me on an element basis (maybe because I used it inside `map()`), I did it by creating a new element and copying the attributes as needed.

```
$items = $('select option').map(function(){

  var
    $source = $(this),
    $copy = $('<li></li>'),
    title = $source.text().replace( /this/, 'that' );

  $copy
    .data( 'additional_info' , $source.val() )
    .text(title);

  return $copy;
});

$('ul').append($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Take him by the word

Taken the Question by Word "how to change tag name?" I would suggest this solution:
If it makes sense or not has to be decided case by case.

My example will "rename" all a-Tags with hyperlinks for SMS with span tags. Maintaining all attributes and content:

```
$('a[href^="sms:"]').each(function(){
  var $t=$(this);
  var $new=$($t.wrap('<div>')
    .parent()
        .html()
        .replace(/^\s*<\s*a/g,'<span')
        .replace(/a\s*>\s*$/g,'span>')
        ).attr('href', null);
  $t.unwrap().replaceWith($new);
});
```

As it does not make any sense to have a span tag with an href attribute I remove that too.
Doing it this way is bulletproof and compatible with all browsers that are supported by jquery.
There are other ways people try to copy all the Attributes to the new Element, but those are not compatible with all browsers.

Although I think it is quite expensive to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery plugin to make "tagName" editable :

```
(function($){
    var $newTag = null;
    $.fn.tagName = function(newTag){
        this.each(function(i, el){
            var $el = $(el);
            $newTag = $("<" + newTag + ">");

            // attributes
            $.each(el.attributes, function(i, attribute){
                $newTag.attr(attribute.nodeName, attribute.nodeValue);
            });
            // content
            $newTag.html($el.html());

            $el.replaceWith($newTag);
        });
        return $newTag;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/03gcnx9v/3/

Answer (score 1):

Yet another script to change the node name

```
function switchElement() {
  $element.each(function (index, oldElement) {
    let $newElement = $('<' + nodeName + '/>');
    _.each($element[0].attributes, function(attribute) {
      $newElement.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    });
    $element.wrapInner($newElement).children().first().unwrap();
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rc296owo/5/

It will copy over the attributes and inner html into a new element and then replace the old one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    $('#switch').bind('click', function(){
        $('p').each(function(){
         $(this).replaceWith($('<div/>').html($(this).html()));
        });
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    background-color: red;
}

div {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello2</p>
<p>Hello3</p>
<button id="switch">replace</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
var renameTag  = function renameTag($obj, new_tag) {
    var obj = $obj.get(0);
    var tag = obj.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var tag_start = new RegExp('^<' + tag);
    var tag_end = new RegExp('<\\/' + tag + '>$');
    var new_html = obj.outerHTML.replace(tag_start, "<" + new_tag).replace(tag_end, '</' + new_tag + '>');
    $obj.replaceWith(new_html);
};
```

ES6

```
const renameTag = function ($obj, new_tag) {
    let obj = $obj.get(0);
    let tag = obj.tagName.toLowerCase();
    let tag_start = new RegExp('^<' + tag);
    let tag_end = new RegExp('<\\/' + tag + '>$');
    let new_html = obj.outerHTML.replace(tag_start, "<" + new_tag).replace(tag_end, '</' + new_tag + '>');
    $obj.replaceWith(new_html);
};
```

Sample code

```
renameTag($(tr),'div');
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try this one also. in this example we can also have attributes of the old tag in new tag*

```js
var newName = document.querySelector('.test').outerHTML.replaceAll('h1', 'h2');
document.querySelector('.test').outerHTML = newName;
```

```html
<h1 class="test">Replace H1 to H2</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you enabled jQuery

1. Get the Html-code of DOM.
2. Replace the TAG in Html-code
3. Convert Html-code to DOM

here comes the sample code,
it is ugly, but work, lol.

```
DOM_old = $('<td>contents</td>');
temp = DOM_old[0].outerHTML;
temp = temp.replace('<td', '<div');
temp = temp.replace('</td>', '</div>');
DOM_new = $(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer have some limitations (like the attributes aren't migrated to the new element), I found a new way to replace tag name without loosing those. But it also have some limitations for example: **The events set to the main element will not migrated to the new element.** Anyways, I'm providing the function. Let me know if you have any better Idea.

#### With Pure Javascript:

```js
function replaceTag(element, new_tag) {
  let outerHTML = element.outerHTML;
  let outerTag = outerHTML
    .match(/<([a-zA-Z]*?)( |>)/)[0]
    .replaceAll("<", "")
    .replaceAll("/", "")
    .replaceAll("=", "")
    .replaceAll(">", "")
    .trim();
  let newHTML_pre = outerHTML.replace(outerTag, new_tag);
  newHTML_pre = newHTML_pre.slice(0, newHTML_pre.length - outerTag.length - 3);
  let newHTML;
  if (outerHTML.endsWith('</' + outerTag + '>')) {
    newHTML = newHTML_pre + '</' + new_tag + '>';
  } else {
    newHTML = newHTML_pre;
  }
  element.outerHTML = newHTML;
}
// let e = document.querySelector('div');
// replaceTag(e, 'img');
```

#### With Jquery:

```js
$.fn.replaceTag = function (new_tag) {
  return this.each(function () {
    let outerHTML = $(this).prop("outerHTML");
    let outerTag = outerHTML
      .match(/<([a-zA-Z]*?)( |>)/)[0]
      .replaceAll("<", "")
      .replaceAll("/", "")
      .replaceAll("=", "")
      .replaceAll(">", "")
      .trim();
    let newHTML_pre = outerHTML.replace(outerTag, new_tag);
    newHTML_pre = newHTML_pre.slice(0, newHTML_pre.length - outerTag.length - 3);
    let newHTML;
    if (outerHTML.endsWith("</" + outerTag + ">")) {
      newHTML = newHTML_pre + "</" + new_tag + ">";
    } else {
      newHTML = newHTML_pre;
    }
    $(this).prop("outerHTML", newHTML);
  });
};
// $('div').replaceTag('img');
```

#### Explanation:

The function replaces the start and end tag of the element's outerHTML with the new tag ignoring the child elements with the same tag name. Sometimes the element doesn't have end tag name like: (`<div />`), in that case it just replace the start tag. That's All.