# can I detect in Jquery if an element has a binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, detect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [test if event handler is bound to an element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)

I have a button with a fairly large script attached to it. I'm binding to this button like so:

```
 $(document).on( "click", '.basketSubmitter' , function(e) {

 ... stuff

 });
```

I can't pin it down, but sometimes the button looses it's binding = I click all I want and nothing happens. The buttons sitting left and right continue to work fine, so there must be something with the button being unbound somewhere. Script is large, so

**Question:**
Is there an easy way to list an elements binding or to detect when an element looses bindings in Jquery?

Thank!

Comment: It's seems this was previously asked here and it's solved:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138543/list-all-bindings-of-an-elment-with-jquery

Comment: see this question (i guess its for debugging purposes) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery

Comment: You could try to use namespaced events to prevent canceling/unbinding the click event from somewhere else: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

Comment: is it possibly due to errors thrown under certain conditions? look in console

Comment: @charlietfl: checked the console on Firebug and iPad - no errors. Strangely the binding is only "lost" on iPad... But if it was from some memory issue, no buttons should work.

Answer (score 1):

This tool will help you to find out the binded events to any DOM element

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

It's good if you want to inspect the dom to find binded events..

Answer (score 1):

Try namespacing your event. For eg click.myFunc

That can be used as

```
$('.basketSubmitter').off('click.myFunc')on( "click.myFunc" , function(e) {

 ... stuff

 });
```