# How to copy all the attributes of one element and apply them to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I copy the attributes of one element to another element?

HTML

```
<select id="foo" class="bar baz" style="display:block" width="100" data-foo="bar">...</select>

<div>No attributes yet</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var $div = $('div');
var $select = $('select');

//now copy the attributes from $select to $div
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy `id`?

Comment: If it is going to copy the `id` attribute you will have a duplicated `id`.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you need to this? There's likely a better solution.

Comment: Don't worry, I will either not copy the ID attrbute or remove the duplicate ID attribute.

Comment: Because I don't want to forget an attribute if I copy each one by hand. Also, I didn't know how to do this, so I wanted to ask so I could learn how to do it in the future.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use the native [`Node#attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.attributes) property: http://jsfiddle.net/SDWHN/16/.

```
var $select = $("select");
var $div = $("div");

var attributes = $select.prop("attributes");

// loop through <select> attributes and apply them on <div>
$.each(attributes, function() {
    $div.attr(this.name, this.value);
});

alert($div.data("foo"));
```

Comment: As a note: attributes array is far from compatible. Yes, it is core, but IE in earlier version treats 'core' properties as it pleases. I use "hackish", but as paradox more compliant way taken from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-is-it-possible-to-clone-all-attributes-on-an-element-and-copy-to-a-different-type-of-element - make node a string representation, change it's tag with regexp and convert back to node. Then I can re-attach data and events. IE version threw errors on copying some of the attributes (ex 'implementation' attribute - did you know it's attached to all tags?)

Comment: Kudos for prepending your variables with '$' when they contain references to jQuery objects. I started this trend in my current company... it makes it MUCH easier to read the code quickly!

Comment: Would like to ask a side question related to this. I tried `$something.prop('attributes')` and it give an array with attributes. One of them is `crossorigin` for an image. I tried `$item.prop('crossorigin')` which is undefined but if I try `$item.prop('src')`, it give result. And then I tried `$item.attr('crossorigin')` which give the value. What is the difference of `.attr()` and `.prop()`? Why is the above situation somewhat different? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @simongcc `.prop` gets a property from the underlying native `Node` object representing the DOM of the element. `.attr` gets the value of a HTML attribute as defined programmatically or via markup.

Answer (score 36):

ES6 syntax one liner:

```
function cloneAttributes(target, source) {
  [...source.attributes].forEach( attr => { target.setAttribute(attr.nodeName ,attr.nodeValue) })
}
```

And as noted in the first comment - you would probably don't want to copy the source id attribute... so this one will save it as a 'data-id' attribute in case you need a reference.

```
function cloneAttributes(target, source) {
  [...source.attributes].forEach( attr => { target.setAttribute(attr.nodeName === "id" ? 'data-id' : attr.nodeName ,attr.nodeValue) })
}
```

Comment: best answer so far. It's 2020.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer. It's clean and can easily be used interchangeably between vanilla JS and jQuery.

Comment: nodeName, nodeValue are deprecated now https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Attr

Comment: What I did was use `attr.name` and `attr.value` instead of `attr.nodeName` and `attr.nodeValue` respectively. It still works as expected.

Answer (score 14):

Pretty Simple

```
function cloneAttributes(element, sourceNode) {
  let attr;
  let attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(sourceNode.attributes);
  while(attr = attributes.pop()) {
    element.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also note that this method does not copy any unnecessary primitive types. It only clones each attribute.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `Array#slice` and `while` instead of just `Array#forEach`?

Comment: Probably for dead browsers compatibility.

Answer (score 11):

[A working solution on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYLcZ/1/)

**EDIT**

Updated jsfiddler

***Javascript***

```
$(function(){
    var destination = $('#adiv').eq(0);
    var source = $('#bdiv')[0];

    for (i = 0; i < source.attributes.length; i++)
    {
        var a = source.attributes[i];
        destination.attr(a.name, a.value);
    }
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="adiv" class="aclass">A class</div>
<div id="bdiv" class="bclass">B class</div>
```

That's copying `#bdiv` attributes to  `#adiv`.

Comment: You should post at least the important part of your code here, if for no other reason than if jsfiddle ever disappears your answer remains.

Comment: @kingjiv, Thank's for advising.

Comment: This seems to have a problem in IE (8) where it finds far too many properties (100+) and jQuery throws a member not found exception when trying to set the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

We could also try extending the jQuery prototype (`$.fn`) object to provide a new method that can be chained to the jQuery() function.

**Here's an extension of @pimvdb's solution to provide a function that copies all attributes**

The usage would be like so:

```
 $(destinationElement).copyAllAttributes(sourceElement);
```

The extension function can be defined like so:

```
(function ($) {

    // Define the function here
    $.fn.copyAllAttributes = function(sourceElement) {

        // 'that' contains a pointer to the destination element
        var that = this;

        // Place holder for all attributes
        var allAttributes = ($(sourceElement) && $(sourceElement).length > 0) ?
            $(sourceElement).prop("attributes") : null;

        // Iterate through attributes and add    
        if (allAttributes && $(that) && $(that).length == 1) {
            $.each(allAttributes, function() {
                // Ensure that class names are not copied but rather added
                if (this.name == "class") {
                    $(that).addClass(this.value);
                } else {
                    that.attr(this.name, this.value);
                }

            });
        }

        return that;
    }; 

})(jQuery);
```

An Example is available at http://jsfiddle.net/roeburg/Z8x8x/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code has unnecessary duplicate jQuery wrappers/initializations. See my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/5eLdcya6/

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
function copyAttributes(from, to)
{
  $($(from)[0].attributes).
    each(function(){$(to).attr(this.nodeName, this.nodeValue);});

  return $(to);
};
```

The return statement lets you write things like:

```
copyAttributes(some_element, $('<div></div>')).append(...) ...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A non-jquery solution:

```
function copy(element){
    var clone = document.createElement(element.nodeName);
    for(key in element){
        clone.setAttribute(key,element[key]);
    }
    return clone;
}
```

It copies methods and other stuff you probably don't need, but hopefully you don't mind.  This code is small and simple.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing same problem and after invested lots of time and effort i am creating this[clone textarea into editable div with same attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_Rocko_96/uy5jg2Lr/)

```
select.getAttributeNames().forEach(attrName => {
  $(div).attr(attrName, inputData.getAttribute(attrName));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very straight to the point solution would be make something like this:

```js
const _$ = domQuery => document.querySelector(domQuery)
let div1 = _$('#div-1')
let div2 = _$('#div-2')

for(attr of div1.attributes) {
  div2.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
}
```

```css
.my-div {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>div-1</h1>
<div atribute-test="test" class="my-div" style="background: red" id="div-1"></div>
<h1>div-2</h1>
<div id="div-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox 22, Node.attributes is no longer supported (not implemented by other browsers and removed from the spec). It is only supported on Element (Element.attributes).

Comment: This doesn't matter at all for OP, he doesn't talk about text or other nodes.

Answer (score -1):

**Javascript solution**

Copy the attributes of old element to the new element

```
const $oldElem = document.querySelector('.old')
const $newElem = document.createElement('div')

Array.from($oldElem.attributes).map(a => {
  $newElem.setAttribute(a.name, a.value)
})
```

Replace the old element with the new element, if required

```
$oldElem.parentNode.replaceChild($newElem, $oldElem)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("div").addClass($('#foo').attr('class'));
```

Comment: my mistake, i thought you wanted to copy the css.

Comment: Although it was a mistake, it's exactly what I was googling for. So, thanks! ;)