# Is it possible transform one DOM element to another? Or copy all attributes from it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible transform one DOM element to another?
By jQuery  or even by JavaScript.

I just to want for example:
get table > thead > tr > th's with all classes, attributes, properties and put it in table > body like as tr > td.

Or maybe is another way for that?

Comment: Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753362/jquery-how-to-copy-all-the-attributes-of-one-element-and-apply-them-to-another

Comment: You can check out this code. I simply replaced the &lt;th and &lt;\th http://jsfiddle.net/5uHMn/1/

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple options.

- You can use jQuery's `clone()`, which will copy everything on/in the DOM node. Then use `append()` to attach the clone to whatever element you want it moved to. Then just remove the original node.
- If you just want the attributes from the DOM node (classes, id, etc.) then you can use the `attributes` array that is present on all DOM nodes. You'd have to loop through each attribute and then set it on the new element individually though. I have yet to find a simple way to just copy everything over. In vanilla Javascript that would look something like this:

  ```
  var originalELement = document.getElementById('original-element-id');
  var newElement = document.createElement('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < originalElement.attributes.length; i++) {
      var attr = originalElement.attributes.item(i);
      newElement.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

when you do element1.append(element2) element2 will move inside element1. append or appendChild. weird but true. append actually means "cut"

Comment: Can you try to elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: did you try the code i wrote?