# How to get node data in JavaScript like inline styles and direction etc

Tags: javascript, html

I have a node like below

```
<body id="hello" dir="auto" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;color:red" bgcolor="green";></body>
```

i want to extract `id="hello" dir="auto" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;color:red" bgcolor="green";` from the body tag and to apply the same to another tag say DIV. How can this be possible.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6753523/218196) doesn't use jQuery for the important part. This one might also be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715447/218196

Comment: Not only Style, i want to copy all the data, like id, dir, bgColor

Comment: I just noticed that the other question is too jQueryish unfortunately (unless you are using jQuery anyways). It's very straightforward to adept it for plain JS though.

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20766701/218196

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like this, no jQuery needed.

```
var newDiv = document.body.cloneNode();
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
newDiv.outerHTML = newDiv.outerHTML.replace(/body/g,"div");
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc2dw/1/)

Or even a cleaner way [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573971/is-it-possible-transform-one-dom-element-to-another-or-copy-all-attributes-from/20766701#20766701)

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    body = document.body;

for (var i = body.attributes.length; i--;) {
    var attr = body.attributes.item(i);
    newDiv.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
}
```

It copy's all the attributes from an element, in this case body, to the new div.

Comment: is there anything to change it directly with node, since changing outer html from the document will not be possible many times.

Comment: Yes that is possible, look at the answers in the links by @FelixKling. I'll add a snippet to my answer.

Comment: Got it... i was expecting something to avoid looping through the attributes. So only was searching for shortcut. If it was copy only style, then easily using node.style.cssText we can take. Similarly without looping through the attributes any short cut is there or not i was checking. Thanks for the update.