# How to rebind an event with new parameters after clone()?

Tags: jquery, events, binding, clone

I'm creating a toggle button with this function: http://pastebin.com/gLkeB7pi
Then I'm cloning this toggle button for a similar use - but not exactly the same. For that purpose, I need the same 'click' behaviour (that is, select/unselect & checkbox) but on the new cloned button.

So I'm trying this:
First, I modified createToggleButton: http://pastebin.com/tFZVafwE
Basically, I passed a checkbox parameter to the click handler by event.data and I modified the internal functions consequently, so that the new toggle checkbox is checked.
Then I did this:

```
var toggle = toggleButton.clone(true); //toggleButton is the toggle inside the div created with createToggleButton()
$(toggle).unbind('click');
$(toggle).bind('click',
    {chkbx: $(toggle).find('input[type=checkbox]')},
    function(evt){toggle.toggle(evt)}
);
```

But then, I can't figure out at all what happens. On click, the new toggle slides up (?!) and the toggle.toggle function is not executed at all (I added a console.log).
So:

1) Am I thinking the right way to do what I wanna do?

2) Which code is actually executed on click and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it. In case anyone stumble upon the same kind of problem:

**First - hacky and not tested - solution:** if you want (or need) to use `clone`, first note that a JS Object method called `toggle` already exists. That was the one being called in my case, instead of the `toggle.toggle` I created. Moreover, the methods created in my createToggleButton function are not copied with `clone`. So, as David said, it's better binding with `$._data( toggleButton[0], 'events' ).click[0].handler;`. Even then, in my case it won't work because `toggle.toggle` calls `toggle.active` or `toggle.deactive` which both don't exist in this context. So it's necessary not to call any side function in the handler.

**Second solution** (better): Don't use `clone`. Reuse `createToggleButton` and manually add the needed HTML attributes (see [jQuery: How to copy all the attributes of one element and apply them to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753362/jquery-how-to-copy-all-the-attributes-of-one-element-and-apply-them-to-another)).

Answer (score 0):

I can’t say much about the toggle code, but if you want to copy a handler, it’s generally best to save the handler into a variable first, f.ex:

```
var handler = function(e) {
    // do stuff
};

toggleButton.bind('click', { john: 'doe' }, handler);

// now clone, attach the same hander but pass some other data

var $clone = toggleButton.clone(); // don’t copy events
$clone.bind('click', { foo: 'bar' }, handler);
```

If you want to "find" a handler you previously attached, you can use `$._data`, f.ex:

```
var handler = $._data( toggleButton[0], 'events' ).click[0].handler;
```

Comment: Well in my situation, the handler is a fixed element of the toggle, so the only change would be `clone()` instead of `clone(true)` and no `unbind`. I'm afraid I observe exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the handler access. Can't upvote you, lacking of rep. :(