# Is there any way to take div and convert it to img tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Let's suppose I have some  element and also have some picture in folder. So what I want to do is to take exactly this div and covert it into img tag using picture that I have as a source.

Comment: Yes, there is. Now, where is your HTML & jQuery/JavaScript code attempt to solve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to change tag name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435871/jquery-how-to-change-tag-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#yourDiv").replaceWith("<img src='yourImage.png' />");
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

> The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new
>   content in its place with a single call.

So really, instead of "converting" the `div` as you ask in your question, this removes the `div` and replaces it with a new `img` element. Which should work exactly as you expected, but it's difficult to say for sure without a clearer question.

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/aASuA/) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can :

```
$(function(){


$('div').each(function(){
   //TEST url used
    $img= $('<img>').attr('src','http://blog.irrashai.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/test-pilot.png');
    $(this).replaceWith($img);
});

});
```

Check my link : http://jsfiddle.net/R2XQp/

My example targets each DIV tag... changed code the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.replaceAll](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) method.

Create a new image:

```
var $image = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'path/to/my/image.png');
$($image).replaceAll('#selector-of-div');
```

However, there might be better ways if you could clarify a bit more exactly why you are replacing a div with an img and what the usecase is :-)

Answer (score 0):

select the div and replace it with the img

```
$("#yourDIVid").replaceWith("<img/>",{src:'yourSource'});
```

[`jquery replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 0):

```
//get it from somewhere
var imgSource;

$('#yourDiv').replaceWith('<img src=")
```

Comment: It looks like you just gave up halfway through writing your answer... obviously, this isn't going to work.

Answer (score -1):

My approach would be

- Take the div's innerHTML
- Create your image tag and append it next to the div
- Append the innerHTML of the div to the image tag
- remove the div from the dom

If you try it and have problems, post your code here.