# Is it possible to change paragraph tag to header tag by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to change a paragraph element by its ID in JavaScript to a `h1`.

My HTML

```
<body>
   <p id="damn"> Hello </p>
</body>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script>
    document.getElementByID("damn").<required missing code to change to h1>
</script>
```

The required result is

```
<body>
   <h1 id="damn"> Hello </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: read the second answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435871/jquery-how-to-change-tag-name

Comment: see here :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function changeTagName(el, newTagName) {
    var n = document.createElement(newTagName);
    var attr = el.attributes;
    for (var i = 0, len = attr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        n.setAttribute(attr[i].name, attr[i].value);
    }
    n.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(n, el);
}

changeTagName(document.getElementById('damn'), 'h1');
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/UuUpk/1/)

Comment: +1 this should be the accepted answer. It maintains all of the original elements attributes and by using innerHTML instead of textContent, it will retain any child elements (such as spans that might have style attached).

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem=document.getElementById("damn");
var parent=elem.parentNode;
var newElement=document.createElement("h1");
newElement.textContent=elem.textContent;
newElement.id=elem.id;
parent.replaceChild(newElement, elem);
```

That should do the trick. Play around with [me](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Z9g/1/).

Comment: Please include newElement.id = elem.id;

Comment: This is close but it won't take the original elements position in relation to its siblings.

Comment: According to the given example, it does its job well. there are no siblings in the example ;)