# Implement React component into html string

Tags: reactjs

I receive html as a string from a CMS.

What I want to achieve, is replacing some of this content, with a React component

Example could be

```
const html = "<div class="example"><h1 class="title>Title</h1></div>"
```

Everytime the HTML string has the class "title" included, I want to replace the h1 element with `<Title />`

Example of component

```
const Title = () => {
 const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)
return <h1 onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)} style={clicked ? {color: 'red'} : {color: 'blue'}>Title</h1>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using this library to convert string to html
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser if you need.
if you want to change tagName to h1 when `class="title"`, please do like this:
[Is it possible to change paragraph tag to header tag by using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463930/is-it-possible-to-change-paragraph-tag-to-header-tag-by-using-javascript)

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)

function changeTagName(el, newTagName) {
    var n = document.createElement(newTagName);
    var attr = el.attributes;
    for (var i = 0, len = attr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        n.setAttribute(attr[i].name, attr[i].value);
    }
    n.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
    n.onClick = () => {setClicked(!clicked)} style={clicked ? {color: 
    'red'} : {color: 'blue'}}
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(n, el);
}

changeTagName(document.getElementById('damn'), 'h1');
```

Comment: But this will not change the challenge, to replace html with a React component

Comment: add n.onClick = () => {} as your expectation