# Remove periods from XML tags

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have a wierd problem where the `XML` is containing `periods (.)` within them.

```
<member>
    <name>ABCD</name>
        <value>         
             <date.of.birth>02.05.2000</date.of.birth>
        </value>                        
</member>
```

Due to this, I have problems parsing the `XML` in `javascript`. I convert this `XML` into `JSON` and use `JSON.parse()`.

Please let me know if there is an efficient way to replace all periods in `XML` Tags using `Javascript` by an underscore or something. Something like the one below

```
<member>
    <name>ABCD</name>
        <value>         
                <date_of_birth>02.05.2000</date_of_birth>
        </value>                        
</member>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool, thanks for making me look up the XML specs and learn that a period is actually a valid character inside an element name. :-)

Comment: @Paul-Jan ... Yea, Period is actually a valid character. I also realized it recently. :)

Comment: @JonHanna ... I have used underscore at start and still works without errors.

Comment: @Kk_112688 Darn it! I completely mis-wrote that, it should have been: ‘In fact the standard calls that out, “Note that COLON, HYPHEN-MINUS, FULL STOP (period), LOW LINE (underscore), and MIDDLE DOT are explicitly permitted.” Though of those, only colon and low line are allowed to start a name.’ Whatever wrong branch my brain took when writing the above I made two mistakes; not only is low line allowed at the start of a name, but hyphen-minus is not.

Comment: @JonHanna ... Thanks for your comment. Wil keep it in mind.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing could be accomplish by using a pure JavaScript:

```js
var text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><member><name>ABCD</name><value><date.of.birth>02.05.2000</date.of.birth></value></member>';

if (window.DOMParser)
{
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
}

// access to you DOM elements:
var e = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('date.of.birth')[0]
```

Then, to replace a tag, you could do:

```js
var d = xmlDoc.createElement('date_of_birth');
d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
e.parentNode.insertBefore(d, e);
e.parentNode.removeChild(e);

// lets see what we have 
xmlDoc
```

[image]

**Update:**

in order to find an element with specific tag name in run time we can do:

```js
 var elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*"); // get all them
 var matched_elements =[];
 for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
 { 
   if ( /\./.test(elements[i].tagName) ) // our filter 
   { 
     matched_elements.push(elements[i]) 
   } 
 }
 matched_elements // contains what we expect
```

Comment: Hi @CodeGroover, I really liked this method. One question though. Can I identify the tags which has periods in run time ?

Comment: I mean, there may be other instances of these in the XML with different tag names. Can it be made generic enough. Something like 

var e = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('*.*');

Comment: Yes, you can do that for example by iterating over child nodes in DOM tree using the 'elementNode.childNodes' property and on each node matched it using regexp. (answer to you first question in comment)

Comment: @Kk_112688 Answered to you second question in comments by updating my primary answer. See above.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using jQuery

I'm not sure it's simple to do this in `JavaScript`.

**Edit:** Have a look at [jQuery: how to change tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435890/802365)

#### Using XSLT

However, doing it in `XSLT` is. You'll simply need to match the dot-named tags with a `xsl:template` and recreate it with custom name.

```
<xsl:template match="date.of.birth">
  <xsl:element name="replace(local-name(), '.', '_')">
    <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I create an `xsl:element` based on old name where I [replace](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_replace.html) `.` (dot) by `_` (underscore)