# Replace <a> link with <nuxt-link> in string variable

Tags: javascript, vue-router, nuxt.js

I retrieve content from a CMS system (WordPress). In the "page.content" variable, links are outputted like so: `<a href="#">`. How can I replace this content with: `<nuxt-link to="#">` on the client side?

The question has been asked before, but no real answers: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2912 - despite this must be a pretty regular usecase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change HTML tag name using Pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489160/change-html-tag-name-using-pure-js)

Answer (score 2):

Simple string replacement should suffice.

```js
const string =  'links are outputted like so: <a href="#">. How can I replace this content with: <nuxt-link to="#">'

const converted = string.replace(/<a/g, '<nuxt-link').replace(/href=/g, 'to=');

console.log(converted)
```

Comment: This will only replace one link in the whole string, to replace all, there must be a global  regex `/g` in the replace: `string.replace(/<a/g, '<nuxt-link').replace(/href=/g, 'to=');`

Comment: @GBWDev - I am not sure the component is rendered, if you simply do it this way. <nuxt-link> is a component.