# Making text bold in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently having a problem replacing the current text with the same text but in **bold**. I've tried the following

```
var valueInRow = $(value).closest(".label.imaged").text();
var result = valueInRow.bold();
$(value).closest(".label.imaged").text().replaceWith(result);
```

But I'm not sure why it doesn't work; Any ideas?

Comment: `<p>text</p>` `$('p').css('font-weight', 900)`

Comment: If you want to replace, like a `<span>` tag with a `<strong>` tag, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3435890/4796321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clearly use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/):

> Wrap an HTML structure around the content of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(value).closest(".label.imaged").wrapInner("<strong />");
```

Comment: Surely setting CSS is preferable to the `strong` element.

Comment: @DBS Agreed. `:)` But some people (like me) hate inline styles and obtrusive code. Agree?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Follow you and many things learned from you Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `.css()` method also

```
var valueInRow= $(value).closest(".label.imaged");
valueInRow.css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers are entirely valid, but I'll add this an alternative that doesn't add any new HTML elements or inline styles.

Creating a CSS rule that's purpose is simply to bold text, such as:

```
.boldText{ font-weight: bold !important; }
```

Will then allow you to bold any element simply by adding that class:

```
$(value).closest(".label.imaged").addClass("boldText");
```

*Note about the use of `!important`: This is usually not recommended CSS as it's often used in the wrong way. However in this case if you add a class called `boldText` to an element, chances are, you will always want it to have bold text.

Comment: This works the best if you need to addClass and also removeClass