# Is it good to change the tagname of a DOM <style> node to something else to make style toggling happen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a CSS like this:

```
<style id="dark">
@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) {
  body..
  ... rules
}
</style>
```

I want to toggle it not only by default OS's settings (which is done by the media query), but also give the user a button to toggle between light and dark.

So what I had thought is to [change the tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435871/jquery-how-to-change-tag-name/3435943) of `style` to something else and hide it.

The way actually works but I don't know whether it is good / the best way to do my task?

Comment: I recommend using a [CSS class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) that you can [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) with JavaScript. What is the actual CSS? Is the declaration applied to the `body`?

Comment: not only applied to body but also applied to many other selectors. due to historical reasons, I have to use a independent `<style>` tag to hold all the `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark)` rules.

Comment: One idea is to use a class on the `body` that indicates dark mode and can be added/removed/toggled with JavaScript. Other declarations can depend on that class, something like `body.dark .another-element { ... }`. I think it might help to see more specifics about your code, including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and see whether I can adapt my code to that style.

Comment: I would suggest using two different css files, its easier to manage and have more control over your future changes. Think of it as template, as there may even exist images, html etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is definitively not the proper way to do this.

The [HTMLStyleElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement) (`<style>`) has a `.disabled` property for this task:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const style = document.querySelector("style");

button.onclick = (evt) => style.disabled = !style.disabled;
```

```css
button { color: red; }
```

```html
<button>click me to toggle color</button>
```

And even `<link>` elements have that property.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

// creates a <link> element pointing to a stylesheet
// containing the single rule "button { color: red; }"
const link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`button { color: red; }`], { type: "text/css" }));
link.onload = (evt) => URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
document.head.append(link);

// works with <link> too
button.onclick = (evt) => link.disabled = !link.disabled;
```

```html
<button>click me to toggle color</button>
```

An other way would be to add a class on a common ancestor, and check for the presence or absence of such class in every rules, but this will force you to repeat a lot of rules. Might still be useful nevertheless.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
select.onchange = (evt) => {
  document.body.classList.remove("shade-auto", "light", "dark");
  document.body.classList.add(select.value);
};
document.body.classList.add(select.value);
```

```css
body.light {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
body.light select {
  background: #EEE;
  color: #222;
}
body.dark {
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
}
body.dark select {
  color: #eee;
  background: #333;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body.shade-auto {
    background: white;
    color: black;
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body.shade-auto {
    background: #222;
    color: #eee;
  }
  body.shade-auto select {
    color: #eee;
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="shade-auto">Auto (respect OS)</option>
  <option value="light">Force Light mode</option>
  <option value="dark">Force Dark mode</option>
</select>
Foo bar
```