# Add a row to change headers of table column and add row on top of header using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I have following table.
[image]

I want to remove city name from column header and put it on top. Like following:
[image]

**Columns with city names are dynamically added in code and can be in any number i.e. 0, 1 to any number.**

Table structure is:

```
<table class="gvv1" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_gvActivities"
style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr style="background-color: buttonface;">
    <th scope="col">
        &nbsp;
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        Cluster
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        Activity
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        Data
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        <b>London_Tasks</b>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        <b>London_Achieved</b>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        <b>Geneva_Tasks</b>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        <b>Geneva_Achieved</b>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="chkSelected_0" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50px; white-space: nowrap;">
        ER.
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50px; white-space: nowrap;">
        Provision
    </td>
    <td style="width: 60px; white-space: nowrap;">
        number
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl00Activitiesl00" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl00Activitiesl01" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl00Activitiesl02" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl00Activitiesl03" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="chkSelected_1" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50px; white-space: nowrap;">
        ER.
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50px; white-space: nowrap;">
        support
    </td>
    <td style="width: 60px; white-space: nowrap;">
        campaign (Numbers)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl0Activities200" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl0Activities201" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl0Activities202" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl0Activities203" type="text" value="-1.00" />
    </td>
</tr>      
</table>
```

Comment: You would have tried something. Post that code please.

Comment: @techfoobar I can add row on top using grid and before in tr:first but these column are dynamic and can be one or 5 or 10. And I am unable to remove the text from column header and put it on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52jZC/

This uses jQuery and will dynamically work with any table of the same structure with the class name `gvv1`. You can change to fit your needs:

```
<script>
// This function was taking from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815683/jquery-javascript-replace-tag-type
(function($) {    
        $.fn.replaceTagName = function(replaceWith) {
                var tags = [],
                        i    = this.length;
                while (i--) {
                        var newElement = document.createElement(replaceWith),
                                thisi      = this[i],
                                thisia     = thisi.attributes;
                        for (var a = thisia.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                                var attrib = thisia[a];
                                newElement.setAttribute(attrib.name, attrib.value);
                        };
                        newElement.innerHTML = thisi.innerHTML;
                        $(thisi).after(newElement).remove();
                        tags[i - 1] = newElement;
                }
                return $(tags);
        };
})(window.jQuery);

$(function() {
        // This formats each table w/ the class 'gvv1' as specified in your question
            $('.gvv1').each(function(i, v) {
            city1 = $(this).find('th:eq(4)').text().split('_');
            city1 = city1[0];
            var city2 = $(this).find('th:eq(6)').text().split('_');
            city2 = city2[0];
            $(this).find('th:eq(4)').text('Tasks');
            $(this).find('th:eq(5)').text('Achieved');
            $(this).find('th:eq(6)').text('Tasks');
            $(this).find('th:eq(7)').text('Achieved');

            $(this).find('th').replaceTagName('td');

            $(this).prepend('<thead><tr><th colspan="4">&nbsp;</th><th colspan="2">' + city1 + '</th><th colspan="2">' + city2 + '</th></tr></thead>');

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the

> `<th>'s`

to a

> `<td>`

first and give that row a class and style appropriately to look like the header you want

```
<tr class="NewClass" style="background-color: buttonface;">
    <td scope="col">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        Cluster
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        Activity
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        Data
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        <b>London_Tasks</b>
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        <b>London_Achieved</b>
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        <b>Geneva_Tasks</b>
    </td>
    <td scope="col">
        <b>Geneva_Achieved</b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

when the event that changes the table is triggered use .before

```
$('TriggerEntity').click(function(){

('.NewClass').before('<tr><th>&nbsp</th><th>London</th>...');

});
```

Comment: this (London) is just an example, I don't know that what would be the location name and City name columns can be in any number so I need to extract text from column header and put in top column.