# How do you replace an HTML tag with another tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have a site I'm working on and it uses 'aside' tags, which I'm not getting IE8 to be able to read no matter what I try, even with an HTML5 Shiv. So, I'm wondering, how would you replace existing tags with other tags with jQuery?

For example, if I wanted to change

```
<aside>
  <h3></h3>
</aside>
```

to

```
<div>
  <h3></h3>
</div>
```

How would that be done?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by replacing the tag?

Comment: `document.createElement('aside')` should allow you to work with the aside tag in IE8. You are using the html5 doctype, right?

Comment: Duplicate question answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9468280/7602 I like the linked not-selected answer better.

Comment: .replaceWith('tag_here');

Comment: I was trying to style the 'aside', but since IE8 won't recognize it, even with document.createElement('aside'), it wasn't reading any of my CSS.

Comment: Ah, i see what's happening. IE8 is incorrectly closing the opening aside immediately, for example `<aside>foo</aside>` is becoming `<aside/>foo</aside/>`, because of this, the replacement will probably be a little bit harder.

Comment: Is there any reason why IE8 is doing that to the aside tag?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('aside').contents().unwrap().wrap('<div/>');
```

- Get the contents of `aside` first.
- Now `unwrap` the contents.
- Now simply, `wrap` the contents inside a new tag, here a `div`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfhgw41/)

---

Also, you can do this using [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method like:

```
$('aside').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<div/>', {
        html: $(this).html()
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzqqf44v/)

Comment: This will incorrectly create superflous `div` due to text nodes (whitespaces) being included when using `.contents`, see http://tinker.io/493db/1

Comment: I'm getting very different results when i try this in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/JpzhL/2/embedded/result/

Comment: How can we apply the attributes of old tag to the new tag? Let's say I have `<div class="bullet first" tabindex="0" aria-label="Slide 1" role="button"><span class="visuallyhidden slide-name">Slide 1</span></div>` HTML markup, how can I change this to `<button class="bullet first" tabindex="0" aria-label="Slide 1" role="button"><span class="visuallyhidden slide-name">Slide 1</span></button>` using jQuery.

Comment: @VikasKhunteta: You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ed6wyed4/
Please let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('aside').replaceWith('<div><h3></h3></div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for every element in the document and it preserves the contents. Using wraps leads to occurrences of many `div` elements if there are line breaks in the contents of the `aside` element.

`$('aside').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<div>"+$(this).html()+"</div>")
});`

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
 $('aside').replaceWith( "<div>" + $('aside').html() + "</div>" );
```

Also using the .html() gives a more dynamic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that replaces HTML5 block tags, preserving the styling on the divs that replace the HTML5 tags.  Simply replacing tags leaves the attributes behind.

```
$('article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, nav, section, source')
    .each(function(){
        var el = $(this),
            html = el.html(),
            attrs = {
                "id": el.attr('id'),
                "classes": el.attr('class'),
                "styles": el.attr('style')
            };

        console.log('Replacing ' + el.prop('tagName') + ', classes: ' + attrs.classes);
        el.replaceWith($('<div></div>').html(html).attr(attrs));
    });
```

(may need a little more work on the source tag, which has "src" and "type" attributes)