# How to change tag name of all html elements which is selected by class name? dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

**strong text**

```css
.my-p{
    display: inline;
}

.my-div {}

.my-bold{
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">First</span></div> line</p>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">Second</span></div> line</p>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">third</span></div> line</p>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">Fourth</span></div> line</p>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">Fifth</span></div> line</p>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">six</span></span></div> line</p>
        <p class="my-p">This is <div class="my-div"><span class="my-bold">seven</span></div> line</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I select all `<div>` elements by class-name `"my-div"`, and change the elements' tag-name to `span`.

I am trying to copy text form many pages from a website, it is has all these **div** in between **p** elements is making hard to copy in a readable manner when pasted it was **pasting in multiple lines** , where ever text is bold there is a **div** inside a **div** there is a **span** element and in that **span** element there is **text** and **div has the same class** name so I am looking for a method to select all div elements of same class name and change there tag name in to span

### The desired output:

[image]

### Present Output:

[image]

I was Tried to select the all div elements by using jQuery
$$(.className) and it gives a list of all elements after that I Manual selected and changed the div to span and then it copied, same as how it appeared

but when I was using the CSS inline it did not worked property

sample
[website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97SlU.png)

```html
      <body>
      <p class="p-tag">
          Lorem ipsum
          <div class="div-tag">
              <span class="span-tag">dolor</span>
          </div> 
          sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
          <div class="div-tag">
              <span class="span-tag">mollitia</span>
          </div>
          ,
      </p>
      
      
      <p class="p-tag" >
          <b class="b-tag" >Lorem ipsum</b> 
          <div  class="div-tag">
              <span class="span-tag">sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
          </div>
      </p>
      
  </body>
```

[when copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbQL.png)

Comment: Where did you get stuck, what did you try? What went wrong with your attempt? What specific help do you need, where's your ("*[mcve]*") code? If you don't want `<div>` elements in your `<p>` elements why are they there? Where are they coming from? Can you change your back-end service or script that's generating this (invalid) HTML? (The HTML is invalid because a block-level element - such as a `<div>` - cannot be inside of a `<p>` element.)

Comment: Assuming you have control of the HTML why not remove `<div class="my-div">` altogether?

Comment: I am trying to copy text form many pages  from a website, it is has all these div in between p elements  is making hard to copy in a readable manner when pasted it was pasting in multiple lines , where ever I text is bold there is a div inside a div there is a span element and in that span element there is text  and div has the same class name 


so I am looking for a method to select all div elements of same class name and change there tag name in to span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer form here

[jQuery/javascript replace tag type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815683/jquery-javascript-replace-tag-type)

First I used this to add scrip in head tag or you can add script manually

```
const link = document.createElement('script');
link.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js");

const newHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
newHead.insertBefore(link, newHead.firstChild);
```

or add manually in head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replaceTagName = function(replaceWith) {
        var tags = [],
            i    = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            var newElement = document.createElement(replaceWith),
                thisi      = this[i],
                thisia     = thisi.attributes;
            for (var a = thisia.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                var attrib = thisia[a];
                newElement.setAttribute(attrib.name, attrib.value);
            };
            newElement.innerHTML = thisi.innerHTML;
            $(thisi).after(newElement).remove();
            tags[i] = newElement;
        }
        return $(tags);
    };
})(window.jQuery);
```

Then

```
$('.my-div').replaceTagName('span');
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` on any block level element to make it appear on one line.

As per your desired output: You can simply use the following CSS:

```
.my-div,
.my-p {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Css is not working in the website do you have know how to change div to span of all elements which is selected by class name  
@ImranRafiqRather

Comment: Try using the same CSS in the `<head></head>` element of your HTML File